# Using \href is not rendering on pdf

Tags: pdftex, rendering, href

I am attempting to use the href package in LaTex to make a link to my GitHub clickable in a resume. I believe that I am using it correctly, but the label remains unclickable.

For background, I am using WSL and creating .dvi files and then converting to .pdf. To even get the .dvi file to work I had to change the 'render method' to 'dvips' under the 'view' tab of Yap (.dvi viewer).

An example of the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\author{Me}

\maketitle

\href{https://github.com/stevend-15}{github.com/stevend-15}

\end{document}
```

I then run `latex test_href.tex` which gives me this output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test_href.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/atveryend/atveryend.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
No file test_href.aux.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty))

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

[1] (./test_href.aux)

Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `test_href.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

 )
Output written on test_href.dvi (1 page, 2684 bytes).
Transcript written on test_href.log.
```

I then run `dvipdfm test_href.dvi` which outputs the following a few times:

```
test_href.dvi -> test_href.pdf
[1
xdvipdfmx:warning: Unparsed material at end of special ignored.

Current input buffer is -->! systemdict /pdfmark known{userdict /?pdfmark sys...<--

xdvipdfmx:warning: Unknown token "SDict"
xdvipdfmx:warning: Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
xdvipdfmx:warning: Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> at page="1" position="(72, 720)" (in PDF)
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> xxx "ps:SDict begin [/Producer (dvips + Distiller)/Title ()/Subje..."
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin [/Producer (dvips + Distiller)/Title ()/Subject ()/Cre...<<
xdvipdfmx:warning: Unparsed material at end of special ignored.

Current input buffer is -->! /DvipsToPDF{72.27 mul Resolution div} def/PDFToD...<--

xdvipdfmx:warning: Unknown token "SDict"
xdvipdfmx:warning: Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
xdvipdfmx:warning: Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> at page="1" position="(72, 720)" (in PDF)
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> xxx "ps:SDict begin /product where{pop product(Distiller)search{p..."
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin /product where{pop product(Distiller)search{pop pop po...<<
xdvipdfmx:warning: Unknown token "SDict"
xdvipdfmx:warning: Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
xdvipdfmx:warning: Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> at page="1" position="(132.768, 705.06)" (in PDF)
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> xxx "ps:SDict begin H.S end"
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin H.S end<<
xdvipdfmx:warning: Unknown token "SDict"
xdvipdfmx:warning: Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
xdvipdfmx:warning: Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> at page="1" position="(132.768, 705.06)" (in PDF)
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> xxx "ps:SDict begin H.R end"
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin H.R end<<
xdvipdfmx:warning: Unknown token "SDict"
xdvipdfmx:warning: Interpreting PS code failed!!! Output might be broken!!!
xdvipdfmx:warning: Interpreting special command ps: (ps:) failed.
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> at page="1" position="(132.768, 705.06)" (in PDF)
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> xxx "ps:SDict begin [/View [/XYZ H.V]/Dest (page.1) cvn /DEST pdf..."
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Reading special command stopped around >>begin [/View [/XYZ H.V]/Dest (page.1) cvn /DEST pdfmark end<<
```

But it stops after a second and gives me this .pdf (shown as an image): [image]

Unfortunately, the label is unclickable.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You may need to run `latex` a second time before `dvipdfm`.  But is there a reason you going via dvi instead of just using `pdflatex`?  It's also possible that you lose the link when you go via dvi.

Comment: if you use dvipdfm(x) you need to tell it hyperref, it assumes the latex+dvips route as default. So use  \usepackage[dvipdfm]{hyperref}

Comment: Independent from the specific issue, your tex installation is also outdated.

Comment: @Teepeemm I am using dvipdfm simply because it was one of the first things I saw and it got working quick.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  thank you very much, it works perfectly!

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer I will look into updating my tex installation.

Comment: Instead of `latex test_href.tex`, try `pdflatex test_href.tex`.  (With your original `\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}`.)

Comment: Thank you @Teepeemm that works as well and saves a step. In general, is there any benefit to using .dvi files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the log, hyperref is loading code for dvips:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
```

and (x)dvipdfmx doesn't like that.

Pass the correct option (`dvipdfm` will work too):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx,unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\author{Me}

\maketitle

\href{https://github.com/stevend-15}{github.com/stevend-15}

\end{document}
```

then hyperref will load `/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvipdfm.def` and the link will work.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Would upvote but do not have enough reputation yet.

Comment: Do not worry Steven☺️. I have done for you.

Comment: @StevenDeVerteuil but you can accept the answer.

Comment: Done! @UlrikeFischer

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks!